# Content of div continuously bouncing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a one-end chat application.
I am getting a error which is content of the middle div "messages" continuously bouncing including scroll bar . How to fix this error ?

And also I cant hold the scroll bar to the top.

Here is my full code :

Main code :

```
<?php
            include 'db.php';
            if(isset($_POST['send']))
            {
                header("Location:chat.php");
                $chat=$_POST['chat'];
                $sql="INSERT INTO chat_info(chat) values('$chat')";
                $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

            }
            ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>chat application</title>
    <style>
        html {
         
  /* THE TRICK */
  margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%);
 
}
        body {

            background-color: white;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
         


        }

        #p1 {

            /* background-color: rgb(241, 243, 242); */
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 50;
            font-weight: bold;

        }

        .div1 {
            background-color: yellowgreen;
            width: 800px;
            margin-left: 350px;
            height: 500px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border: 3px solid rgb(227, 33, 33);

        }

        .da {
            /* margin-top: -10px; */
            height: 40px;
            background-color: rgb(48, 145, 231);
            border: 3px solid rgb(236, 239, 240);
        }

        #chat {
            width: 600px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        #chat{
            border: 2px solid black;
            display: flex;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            float: left;
        }
        #sendbutton{
            /* margin-top: -100px; */
            border: 2px solid red;
            padding-top: -30px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 40px;
            float: left;
            /* margin-top: 400px; */
            margin-left: 12px;
            /* margin-bottom: 30px; */
            /* align-items: center; */
        }
        .btn{
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        .div2{
        /* overflow-y: scroll; */
        border:3px solid purple;
        /* position: fixed; */
        height:350px;
        width: 800px;
        }
        #td1{
            float: right;
            margin-left:400px;
            background-color:white;
            border-radius:5px;
            height:30px;
            padding :5px;
            /* margin:3px; */
            margin-top:3px;
        }
        #td2{
            /* float:right; */
        }
       
        #messages{
           
            height:350px;
            overflow-y:scroll !important;
            /* scroll-behavior: smooth; */
            overscroll-behavior: none;
          
           
   
        }
 
   
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="da">
            <p id="p1">Lets Chat </p>
        </div>
        <div class="div2" id="messages">
            <div class="message">
                  <table >
                    <?php
                    //error_reporting(0);
                    include 'db.php';
                    $sql1="SELECT * from chat_info";
                    $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
                    while($info=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
                    {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="td1"><?php echo $info['chat']; ?></td>
                            <td id="td2"><?php echo formatDate($info['date']);?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                     }
                    ?>
                </table>   
            </div>
         </div>
        <script>
  const messages = document.getElementById('messages');
function appendMessage() {
    const message = document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0];
  const newMessage = message.cloneNode(true);
  messages.appendChild(newMessage);
}

function getMessages() {
    // Prior to getting your messages.
  shouldScroll = messages.scrollTop + messages.clientHeight === messages.scrollHeight;
  /*
   * Get your messages, we'll just simulate it by appending a new one syncronously.
   */
  appendMessage();
  // After getting your messages.
  if (!shouldScroll) {
    scrollToBottom();
  }
}

function scrollToBottom() {
  messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
}

scrollToBottom();

setInterval(getMessages, 100);
        </script>
     
       
        <div class="writearea">
            <form action="chat.php" method="post">
                <textarea name="chat" id="chat" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="write a message" required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="sendbutton" class="btn">
            </form>
 
          
        </div>

      
      

    </div>
</body>

         
</html>
```

An extra PHP function just to connect with the database :

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$db="chat";
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,"",$db);
if(! function_exists('formatDate'))
{
    function formatDate($date){
    return date('g:i a',strtotime($date));
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are constantly adding new messages even if none are there to add. This line of code `setInterval(getMessages, 100);` adds a a new message every 0.1 second and every time a message is added the page automatically scrolls to the  bottom, hence why you cant scroll to the top.

You could try either increasing the interval or implementing a check for empty messages like this:

```
if (! newMessage.textContent === ""){
    messages.appendChild(newMessage);
}
```